# Solving a system of matrix equations using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, equation, differential-equations

I have a system of three equations that I'd like to solve via MATLAB, and I'm a bit confused on how to go about doing it.

I have three equations:

```
A = R*P1
B = R*P2
C = R*P3
```

`A, B, C`, and `P1, P2`, and `P3` are `3x1` matrices, while `R` is a `3x3` matrix. `R` is the same for all three equations.

I need to find `R`, and am given `A, B, C`, and the `P's`.

I wanted to use `fsolve`, but it seems that `fsolve` doesn't work when the variables are matrices. What is an alternative method that you would recommend using?

Just making up some numbers to work with:

```
P1 = [1;1;1];
P2 = [2;3;4];
P3 = [5;4;3];

R = [2 4 5; 1 5 4; 1 2 3];
```

Which would mean that:

```
A = [11;10;6];
B = [36;33;20];
C = [41;37;22];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `A, B, C, P1, P2, P3` are all numerical, why don't you simply use the `ldivide` or `\` operator?  This will allow you to solve your linear system directly.  I can see that you have the following relationships:

```
R*P1 = A
R*P2 = B
R*P3 = C
```

You can see that each matrix equation yields three constraints.  What you can do is create one system that encapsulates all matrix equations together thus yielding 9 constraints.  As such, you'll need to reformulate this to be able to solve for your coefficients in your matrix `R` differently.  To do this, we need to reshape your matrix `R` such that it becomes a 9-element vector.  In other words, we can then reformulate your system like so:

```
[P1 0 0 0 0 0 0]    [R1]   [     ]
[0 0 0 P1 0 0 0]    [R2]   [  A  ]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 P1]    [R3]   [     ]
[P2 0 0 0 0 0 0]    [R4]   [     ]
[0 0 0 P2 0 0 0]  * [R5] = [  B  ]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 P2]    [R6]   [     ]    
[P3 0 0 0 0 0 0]    [R7]   [     ]
[0 0 0 P3 0 0 0]    [R8]   [  C  ]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 P3]    [R9]   [     ]

     P           *   R   =    D
```

You'll see that we have a 9 x 9 matrix called `P`, our matrix `R` which is reshaped into a vector so that we can solve for the coefficients and `D` are `A,B,C` concatenated together into one vector.  `R1` to `R9` are the coefficients of the matrix `R` that are read from left to right and top to bottom.

Therefore, to find your coefficients in your matrix, simply do:

```
R = P^{-1}*D
```

As such, simply construct the matrix `P` and vector `D` like so:

```
P = [P1.' zeros(1,6); zeros(1,3) P1.' zeros(1,3); zeros(1,6) P1.'; ...
P2.' zeros(1,6); zeros(1,3) P2.' zeros(1,3); zeros(1,6) P2.'; ...
P3.' zeros(1,6); zeros(1,3) P3.' zeros(1,3); zeros(1,6) P3.'];

D = [A; B; C];
```

Now, simply solve for `R` and reshape it back into a 3 x 3 matrix.  Therefore:

```
R = P \ D;
R = reshape(R, 3, 3).';
```

`reshape` turns our vector into a 3 x 3 matrix, but it constructs the matrix in **column**-major format, so you need to transpose the result after you call `reshape`.  With your example, this is what we get.  I construct `P1, P2, P3, A, B, C`, then use the code I had from before:

```
P1 = [1;1;1];
P2 = [2;3;4];
P3 = [5;4;3];

A = [11;10;6];
B = [36;33;20];
C = [41;37;22];

P = [P1.' zeros(1,6); zeros(1,3) P1.' zeros(1,3); zeros(1,6) P1.'; ...
P2.' zeros(1,6); zeros(1,3) P2.' zeros(1,3); zeros(1,6) P2.'; ...
P3.' zeros(1,6); zeros(1,3) P3.' zeros(1,3); zeros(1,6) P3.'];

D = [A; B; C];

R = P \ D;
R = reshape(R, 3, 3).';
```

---

To verify that `R` is correct, do:

```
A1 = R*P1;
B1 = R*P2;
C1 = R*P3;
```

We get for each:

```
A1 =

    11
    10
     6

B1 =

    36
    33
    20

C1 =

    41
    37
    22
```

This matches up with your example.  However, note that you may get a warning that `R` is ill-conditioned.  This is because you may not have enough constraints to properly find a unique inverse.  You may have to add more constraints to get a unique inverse, but if you can't, then use this with caution.

Comment: This works! I appreciate your help! I'm not too good at linear algebra yet. I can't wait until I can look at something like this and see what you saw.

Comment: @TheTreeMan my pleasure! I hope you weren't confused with the linear algebra formulation. Didn't know how well you knew that stuff. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to flatten out the matrices inside of the `solve` function?  There is a `collect` function in MATLAB that collects coefficients, but you need to check if it works with supplying a row matrix, as opposed to a sum. (maybe sum(row matrix) - if it also combines like terms)

Something like:

```
[x,y,x] = solve(sum(R*P1)==A, sum(R*P2)==B, sum(R*P3)==C, x,y,z)
```

or the `fsolve` function